# I want to add meta box but its not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to show a meta box which inputs the product code from Woocommerce products and display it to a page. For that reason, I am trying to add a meta box with this functionality. But the meta box is not showing in the custom post type.

These are my codes:

```
add_action('init', 'add_gng_offer');

function add_gng_offer() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'GnG Offer',
        'singular_name' => 'GnG Offer',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Offer',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new Offer',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Offer',
        'new_item' => 'Add New Offer',
        'view_items' => 'View Offers',
        'search_items' => 'Search Offers',
        'not_found' => 'No Offers Found',
        'not_found_trash' => 'No Offers Found In Trash',
    );

    $supports = array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'thumbnail',
        'comments',
        'revisions'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => $supports,
        'public' => true,
        'capablity_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'GnG Offers'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
        'register_meta_box' => '',
    );

    register_post_type('GnG Offers', $args);
}

//Creating meta Boxes for Custom Post Type

function product_id_meta_box () {
    add_meta_box(
        'product_id',
        'Product Field',
        'product_function_callback',
        'GnG Offer',
        'side',
        'default'
    );
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'product_id_meta_box');
```

And another problem how can I make this kind of functionality where I input products id and It will show the products in a certain page.

Comment: Which version of WooCommerce are you running?

Comment: woocommerce 4.4.1